# Evaluate $\int_1^2 \ln(x) \max (x+1, x^2-1) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>    $$\int_1^2 \ln(x) \max (x+1, x^2-1)\, dx$$
>   We have $ g:[1,2]\rightarrow R$ , $g(x) = \max (x+1, x^2-1) $

So, what i've tried is to write 
$g(x)= \max (x+1, x^2-1)$ like : 
 $x^2-1\geq x+1$  and $x+1\geq x^2-1$ . Then, i've tried to find the set of values for $g(x)$ but when i am trying to evaluate the integral it just doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: $x+1\geq x^2-1$ for all $x\in [1,2]$.

Comment: You know that $max(a,b) = b$ if $b > a$. When is $x+1$ greater than $x^2-1$? _Hint:_ make a drawing (or solve $x+1 = x^2 - 1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But $$x^2-1\leq x+1$$ gives $$x^2-x-2\leq0$$ or $$-1\leq x\leq2,$$ which says that we need to evaluate 
$$\int\limits_1^2(x+1)\ln{x}dx.$$
Can you and it now?

I got $4\ln2-\frac{7}{4}.$

Comment: Yes, thank you !

Comment: @Jon9 You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for $x\in [1,2]$,

$$\max (x+1, x^2-1)=(x+1)\max(1,x-1) = (x+1)\cdot 1=x+1$$